Receiving synchronized video and audio frames from a "USB Camera" for real-time processing with GStreamer
I am seeking guidance on developing a system that integrates a camera and GStreamer to receive a live video and audio stream. My primary objective is to achieve synchronous reception of video and audio, with both video frames and audio samples at a rate of 60 frames per second, ensuring seamless synchronization. Specifically, I aim to accompany each video frame with (48000/60)=800 audio samples to maintain synchronization integrity.
Furthermore, my ultimate goal is to process real-time video data in OpenCV and audio data in PortAudio using C++. While I have explored various options, including GStreamer, I haven't yet found a more suitable solution for capturing video and audio frames.
As a beginner with GStreamer, I attempted to combine a camera with GStreamer to receive a live video and audio stream. However, due to my limited experience and basic understanding of GStreamer, I encountered difficulties in achieving the expected results. I tried to follow some basic tutorials and examples, but I struggled to implement the necessary steps correctly. I expected to successfully set up the system to receive synchronized video and audio streams, but I faced challenges in understanding and applying the concepts effectively. As a result, I was unable to achieve the desired outcome.
Additionally, I tried using the provided code snippet to read and decode frames for OpenCV. Although I attempted to adapt it to my needs, I encountered some issues in integrating it with the rest of my project.
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define SAMPLE_RATE 48000
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER 800

struct AudioVideoFrame {
    cv::Mat video_frame;
    std::vector<float> audio_samples;
};

static GstFlowReturn new_sample(GstElement *sink, gpointer user_data) {
    AudioVideoFrame* frame = static_cast<AudioVideoFrame*>(user_data);
    GstSample *sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(GST_APP_SINK(sink));
    GstBuffer *buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
    GstMapInfo map;
    gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

    if (sink == gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(sink), "videosink")) {
        frame->video_frame = cv::Mat(720, 1280, CV_8UC3, (char*)map.data).clone();
    } else if (sink == gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(sink), "audiosink")) {
        frame->audio_samples.resize(map.size / sizeof(float));
        memcpy(frame->audio_samples.data(), map.data, map.size);
    }

    gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
    gst_sample_unref(sample);

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    const char* pipelineDesc =
        "mfvideosrc device-path=\"\\\\?\\usb#vid_1e45&pid_3035&mi_00#6&35de4ec0&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\\global\" ! video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=60/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink name=videosink sync=true "
        "wasapisrc device=\"{0.0.1.00000000}.{fb11cbb1-5d84-489c-bacc-e7cbbde9c673}\" ! audio/x-raw, format=F32LE, rate=48000, channels=1 ! queue ! appsink name=audiosink sync=true";

    GError *err = nullptr;
    GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch(pipelineDesc, &err);

    if (err) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating pipeline: " << err->message << std::endl;
        g_clear_error(&err);
        return -1;
    }

    GstElement *video_sink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "videosink");
    GstElement *audio_sink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "audiosink");

    AudioVideoFrame frame;
    g_signal_connect(video_sink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(new_sample), &frame);
    g_signal_connect(audio_sink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(new_sample), &frame);

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    while (true) {
        if (!frame.video_frame.empty()) {
            cv::imshow("Frame", frame.video_frame);
            if (cv::waitKey(15) == 27) break;
        }
    }

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(video_sink);
    gst_object_unref(audio_sink);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}

Any advice on the necessary steps to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
edit:
My goal is to fill this struct synchronously:
struct AudioVideoFrame {
    cv::Mat video_frame;
    std::vector<float> audio_samples;
};

In my application, this structure will be stored in a shared buffer to be used by other parts of the program. However, the current code, which I have revised, is not working and the program crashes. I'm not sure if my approach is correct. What is the proper method to achieve this?
When I run the gst_device_monitor command in the CMD, I get the following output for my HBVCAM OV9281 1MP HD 120FPS Black and White USB Global Shutter Camera Module:
For the video source:
Device found:

    name  : USB Camera
    class : Source/Video
    caps  : video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=10000000/83333, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=60/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=640, height=480, framerate=10000000/83333, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            video/x-raw, format=YUY2, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=2:4:0:1, chroma-site=dv
            image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720, framerate=10000000/83333, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720, framerate=60/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720, framerate=25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
            image/jpeg, width=640, height=480, framerate=10000000/83333, pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1, colorimetry=1:4:0:1
    properties:
            device.api = mediafoundation
            device.path = \\?\usb#vid_1e45&pid_3035&mi_00#6&35de4ec0&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\global
            device.name = USB Camera
    gst-launch-1.0 mfvideosrc device-path="\\\\?\usb#vid_1e45&pid_3035&mi_00#6&35de4ec0&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\global" ! ...

And for the audio source (microphone):
Device found:

    name  : Microphone (Magic Mic)
    class : Audio/Source
    caps  : audio/x-raw, format=F32LE, layout=interleaved, rate=48000, channels=1, channel-mask=0x0000000000000004
    properties:
            device.api = wasapi
            device.strid = {0.0.1.00000000}.{fb11cbb1-5d84-489c-bacc-e7cbbde9c673}
            wasapi.device.description = Microphone (Magic Mic)
    gst-launch-1.0 wasapisrc device="\{0.0.1.00000000\}.\{fb11cbb1-5d84-489c-bacc-e7cbbde9c673\}" ! ...

I have executed the following command to create a synchronized MP4 video file with AAC audio from my camera device with Media Foundation API and a WASAPI audio input device:
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
mfvideosrc device-path="\\\\?\\usb#vid_1e45&pid_3035&mi_00#6&35de4ec0&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\\global" \
! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=1280,height=720,framerate=60/1 \
! videoconvert \
! queue \
! x264enc tune=zerolatency \
! queue \
! mp4mux name=mux \
! filesink location=output.mp4 \
wasapisrc device="{0.0.1.00000000}.{fb11cbb1-5d84-489c-bacc-e7cbbde9c673}" \
! queue \
! audioconvert \
! audioresample \
! voaacenc \
! aacparse \
! queue \
! mux.

I first retrieved video from my camera in NV12 format with dimensions of 1280x720 and a frame rate of 60 frames per second. Then, I converted it to H.264 format and simultaneously captured audio from the WASAPI audio input device. Subsequently, I combined the video and audio using mp4mux and saved them into the output.mp4 file. This process ensured the creation of a synchronized video file with AAC audio.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

"Specifically, I aim to accompany each video frame with 44100/60 audio samples to maintain synchronization integrity."  Yeah, well, what if you don't get 60 frames from your camera every second?  And, why 44.1 kHz anyway, why not 48 kHz which is standard audio-for-video and evenly divisible by your chosen frame rate?  I think you should rephrase your question... if you can get MediaFoundation to capture audio+video for you, then the synchronization is automatically handled.

Thank you for your response. I appreciate your suggestions and am open to using a sample rate of 48 kHz, as it is the standard for audio-for-video. The camera I am using is an HBVCAM OV9281 1MP HD 120FPS Black and White USB Global Shutter Camera Module. Is it possible for the frame rate to drop and affect synchronization? My main goal is to use a GStreamer pipeline to capture audio and video frames synchronously, ensuring each video frame is accompanied by a corresponding audio buffer of 800 samples. How can I set up a GStreamer pipeline to achieve this? Thank you.

Is your stream working?
mfvideosrc plugin hasn't "device-id" argument , try to replace it with "device-index"

Thank you very much for your response. Yes, the stream is working. I will definitely try replacing "device-id" with "device-index" as you suggested, and I will edit my question accordingly.
